# Heroku Procfile for Perfect 2.0

Tags: swift, heroku, procfile, perfect, swift-package-manager

I am trying to deploy Perfect 2.0 (which uses the swift package manager) on Heroku. A [current build pack for Swift 3 and Perfect 2.0](https://github.com/theam/Perfect-Heroku-Buildpack/) exists and I have tested and pushed the below template with this buildpack to a heroku app successfully without build errors. In particular, I am trying to get [Perfect's base template example](https://github.com/PerfectlySoft/PerfectTemplate)--which runs fine locally--to deploy to heroku as a proof of concept. The problem, however, is that this build pack requires a top-level Procfile to inform heroku as to how to access the perfect server. In Perfect 1.0 this procfile was simply `web: perfectserverhttp --port $PORT`, but with this new procfile `perfectserverhttp` is not a recognized command. In my heroku logs it errors with `bash: perfectserverhttp: command not found`. What is the appropriate way to handle this? i.e. how should I construct my procfile, and with what command do I access my server instance? I can get things to run locally by creating a procfile with `web: .build/debug/<given_package.swift_name>`, but this does not translate to a deployment on heroku.

Comment: Do you have a pointer to the exact code you are trying to deploy? The code you point at is the top-level project, not an example project.

Comment: Fixed the link. Note that the only difference between that depository and what I tried to deployed is a Procfile added at the top level.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've forked that project and made a [Heroku Button deployable version here](https://github.com/jonmountjoy/PerfectTemplate#deploy-to-heroku).  In order to get that working, I checked out the sample app, and found that the build dumped the binary in `.build/release/PerfectTemplate`, so your Procfile should be:

`web: .build/release/PerfectTemplate --port $PORT`

Note, you also want to set the `$PORT`.  If you've deployed but failed prior to this, you'll also want to make sure you scale up the web dyno: `heroku ps:scale web=1`.